# Dockerfile CMD Works on MacOS, Fails on Linux

Tags: linux, docker, build, dockerfile

The Dockerfile I have used for a long time to build containers on MacOS fails to create a viable container when build is performed on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04). The image builds, but then k8s cannot spin up the container. The error log says "/bin/sh: ./dgs: not found".  Have tried many permutations, but it seems like the environment inside the container changed somehow. I can even put in an `ls -la` and see the executable listed in stdout, but CMD cannot see it.

build folder:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 user1 user1     4096 Jun 21 16:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 user1 user1     4096 Jun 21 16:19 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1   257867 Jun 21 16:20 ca-certificates.crt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user1 user1 15826392 Jun 21 16:40 dgs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1      151 Jun 21 16:59 Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.6
COPY ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
WORKDIR /home
COPY ./dgs dgs
RUN ls -la
EXPOSE 8090
CMD ./dgs
```

docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.1
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.6
 Git commit:        4c52b90
 Built:             Wed Jan  9 19:35:23 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.1
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       4c52b90
  Built:            Wed Jan  9 19:02:44 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Comment: maybe you should change the COPY layer of the Dockerfile. Be careful with the dot. try this `./dgs ./dgs`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Alas, the container terminates with this error:
`/bin/sh: ./dgs: not found`

Answer (score 0):

I would be more explicit:

```
WORKDIR /home
COPY ./dgs /home/dgs
RUN chmod +x /home/dgs
CMD ["/home/dgs"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, this one terminates with `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`.  Pretty perplexing.

I wonder if this problem has anything to do with this issue:

https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/561

Comment: I discovered these: https://github.com/riggraz/astuto/issues/9 and https://github.com/ArkArk/latexmk-docker/issues/1. Might these suggest something related to this new issue? I realize that they are discussing very specific projects and the context is specifically related to Windows 10, but the solutions might point you in the right direction.